# Permutations of dictionary in python

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I have a dictionary like this -

```
{'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 4}
```

I want to generate a list like this -

```
[{'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 4},
 {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 0, 'D': 4},
 {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 1, 'D': 4},
 {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 5}]
```

What is the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What rules do you have? Some of the numbers in your 'permutations' seem to come from no-where.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should've said what is the most pythonic way to do this? Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: And the values in the permutations should be increased by 1 from the source one.

Comment: as @AlexThornton asked, where those `1`s and `5` are coming from? Please provide full input and some explanation about rules.

Comment: Permutation means reorder elements, but your values just changed, value of each key in each step. It's not what you call permutation I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't think these are technically permutations.

Comment: if you care for orders of elements, dictionary is not the best choice, as it is by default unordered collection. You should consider using tuples or lists instead.

Comment: I'm taking each element and increasing the value by 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use list comprehension and dictionary comprehension together, like this

```
d = {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 4}
print [{key1: d[key1] + (key1 == key) for key1 in d} for key in d]
```

**Output**

```
[{'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 4},
 {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 1, 'D': 4},
 {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 0, 'D': 4},
 {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 5}]
```

The idea is to generate a new dictionary for each `key`, and when the `key` matches the key of the dictionary being constructed with dictionary comprehension, then add `1` to it. `(key1 == key)` will evaluate to `1` only when both the keys match, otherwise it will be zero.

Comment: @Tim Thanks Removed that :) I was about write a normal loop based solution, but I got the comprehension idea. So, forgot to remove that :)